# What jQuery plugin of tables choose for Spring MVC?

Tags: jquery, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa, thymeleaf

I use Thymeleaf as my template engine.

I need to have the ability to create tables dynamically. I don't know in advance which columns should be output. It needs to read from the data source. I have to search by all columns, sort them.

What free plugin for jQuery can I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been working with spring + thymeleaf for a while and the most resourceful one has been [DataTables](https://datatables.net/). It has been around since 2007 and has plenty of documentation and "plugin" libs to do pretty much everything you can think of.

Now if you are feeling a bit bolder, there's one big competitor, [Tabulator](http://tabulator.info/). It feels way more modern both in appearance and code wise, but it lacks some of the more specific functionallity yet (it's in active development). You can check their roadmap here: [Tabulator Roadmap](https://trello.com/b/rPZ0Yavc/tabulator-roadmap)

Comment: @jorge-v I forgot to say that I need to edit the table and I use Bootstrap. What are you think about these capabilities in DataTables and Tabulator? I know that DataTables can use Bootstrap styles. But Editor plugin for DataTables is commercial.

Comment: I found Tabulator use Bootstrap 4 Theme. And I can edit data in the table. I like Tabulator.

Comment: No worries, was editing accordigly to say just that :P Tabulator is the future.

Answer (score 2):

You can Use [DataTables plug-in](https://datatables.net/)

**Controller**:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/my/url/list")
public ResponseEntity listAllTable(@RequestParam("draw") int draw,
                                  @RequestParam("start") int start,
                                  @RequestParam("length") int length) {

    int page = start / length; //Calculate page number

    Pageable pageable = PageRequest.of(
            page,
            length ,
            new Sort(
                    Sort.Direction.DESC ,
                    "name"
            )
    ) ;

    Page<MyEntity> responseData = repository.findAll(pageable);

    DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();

    dataTable.setData(responseData.getContent());
    dataTable.setRecordsTotal(responseData.getTotalElements());
    dataTable.setRecordsFiltered(responseData.getTotalElements());

    dataTable.setDraw(draw);
    dataTable.setStart(start);

    return ResponseEntity.ok(dataTable);

}
```

**DataTable Class**:

```
public class DataTable<T> {

    private int draw;
    private int start;
    private long recordsTotal;
    private long recordsFiltered;
    private List<T> data;


    // setter and getter ...

}
```

**javascript**:

```
$('#mainTable').DataTable({
    "processing": true,
    "serverSide": true,
    "pageLength": 10,
    "searching": false,
    "info" : true,
    "ajax": {
        "url": "/my/url/list",
        "method":"get",
        "dataSrc": function (response) {

            var data = response.data; // your data list

            var all = [];

            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {


                var row = {

                    rows: response.start + i + 1,
                    name: data[i].name, // name ... ,
                    validFrom: data[i].validFrom,
                    validTo: data[i].validTo,
                    amount: data[i].amount,
                    currency: data[i].currency,

                };
                all.push(row);
            }
            return all;
        }

    },
    "columns": [
        { "data": "name"},
        { "data": "validFrom"},
        { "data": "validTo"},
        { "data": "amount"},
        { "data": "currency"}
    ]
});
```